# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'order' between objects in different contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

The `orderDetail` is related with `consume`. The `consume` was fetched from `CoreDataContext` as a parameter passed to here and was exist.

```
orderDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OrderDetail" inManagedObjectContext:CoreDataContext];
orderDetail.order = consume
```

But this code throws an exception:

> Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'order' between objects in different contexts

I checking the exception with `NSLog`

```
NSLog(@"%@", orderDetail.managedObjectContext);
NSLog(@"%@", consume.managedObjectContext);
```

Then I found that `orderDetail.managedObjectContext` exists, but the `consume.managedObjectContext` is `nil`

Is this why the exception threw? I don't know why this happened.

---

**Update my question,more info:**

**First**
I have only one Context

**Second**
this is happened when I delete the `consume-entity` and reinsert `consume-entity`:
When I push A viewController to B viewController(B viewWillAppear) I request the `orderDetail` and established the relation of `consume`,when I pop to `A` in method `viewWillAppear` I request consume ,when I received data I called

```
 [ CoreDataContext performBlock:^{
              [Consume cleanTheContext:CoreDataContext];...
... ... ... ...
                for (NSDictionary *consume in consumes) {
                    [Consume consumeWithLecaiInfo:consume inManagedObjectContext:CoreDataContext byUser:user];

       }];
```

to clean the old `consume` and insert new `consume` (I know I should update `consume` ,rather than delete and reinsert,but I don't know why `consume` lost it's managedObjectContext in this way)

In reality this error occur once in a while , push A,pop B, push A, pop B ... exception threw out .

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explanatory, you can modify you code to retrieve `consume` object from the same context where you create `orderDetail`:

```
OrderDetail *orderDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OrderDetail" inManagedObjectContext:CoreDataContext]; 
orderDetail.order = [CoreDataContext objectWithID:consume.objectID];
```

`objectID` is a proper way to transfer objects from one `NSManagedObjectContext` to another

Comment: Second context is `nil` therefore he is not transferring objects around between contexts.

Comment: You can use any context for that purpose

Comment: What?  Your comment doesn't make any sense.  OP is clearly NOT using two contexts.

Comment: I did't use two context,and I have update my question , appreciate very much.

Answer (score 0):

For a relationship to be formed both objects must be created from the **same** `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Normally this is not an issue because your UI should be using a single context and your creation of objects should be using `NSEntityDescription.insert...`.

Since you have a `nil` context in one of your objects, that means you are creating it either with a `nil` context somewhere or you are intentionally passing a `nil` into `NSManagedObjectContext.init...`.  Either situation is a problem.

Trace your creation code and put breakpoints in.  Find where the `nil` is and fix it.

Comment: I fetched the consume from CoreDataContext ,so it should have a NSManagedObjectContext. I have update my question ,can you help analyse the question . Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer.  Somewhere in your code, your reference to the context is `nil` when you create the new `Consume` object.  Walk through the creation code, put breakpoints wherever you call `[[NSManagedObject alloc] init...]` or `[NSEntityDescription insert...` and find where the context is `nil`.

Comment: I can sure the consume passed to B viewController has it's managedObjectContext , but when I requested the orderDetail and passed the consume to this request's callback block ,in callback block consume lost it's context.